# Bash rename files in folder by stripping out characters

Tags: awk, sed

I am running ubuntu and I have little experience with sed and awk. 
I would like to rename files with the following:

```
ITIS50V_PHYS_LANDFORM_ARTIFIC_EXP_Areal_2014_09.shp    
ITIS50V_LCLU_LANDCOVER_EXP_2014_03.dbf    
ITIS50V_CULT_INDUSTRIAL_EXP_Linear_2014_02.shx
```

I would like to rename them to :

```
ITIS50V_PHYS_LANDFORM_ARTIFIC.shp    
ITIS50V_LCLU_LANDCOVER.dbf    
ITIS50V_CULT_INDUSTRIAL.shx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For renaming files, you could simply use the rename utility.

```
rename 's/_EXP_.*?(?=.[^.]*$)//' *.*
```

Try the above command on the directory where the files you want to rename are located.